# Question on Borel sets

Tags: measure-theory

I have this lemma:

> Let $X$ be a topological space and $Y\subset X$. Then 
>   $\mathcal{B}(Y)=\mathcal{B}(X)\cap Y$ (where $\mathcal{B}(X)\cap Y$ 
>   denotes $\lbrace B\cap Y ; B\in \mathcal{B}(X)\rbrace$
>
> Proof:
>
> The embedding map $i:Y\rightarrow X$ is continuous, hence Borel
>   measurable , and **if $B\in \mathcal{B}(X),i^{-1}(B)=B\cap Y$**
>   belongs to $\mathcal{B}(Y)$. That proves $\mathcal{B}(X)\cap Y \subset
> \mathcal{B}(Y)$.
>
> Conversely ....

I don't understand why :if $B\in \mathcal{B}(X),i^{-1}(B)=B\cap Y$

Please,

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x \in Y$. If $i(x) \in B$, then $x \in B$ so $x \in B \cap Y$. Now, let $x \in B \cap Y$. Then $i(x) \in B$.

Answer (score 1):

Forget everything except that (i) $Y\subseteq X$, (ii) $B\subseteq X$, and (iii) $i:Y\to X$ is defined by $i(y)=y$ for every $y\in Y$. Now, let $y\in Y$. The condition that $y\in i^{-1}(B)$ is equivalent to $i(y)\in B$, that is, $y\in Y$ and $y\in B$. QED.